# Scale fonts in common controls for DPI aware applications

Tags: winapi

In my DPI aware application everything scales correctly except fonts in **common controls**.

Here are two buttons when DPI is at 96 (100% scaling in system settings)

[image]

Here is how it looks when DPI changes to 175% in system settings:

[image]

Buttons are correctly resized however font size remains the same as you can see from pictures.

Here is handler function for `WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT`

```
// Handler for WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT
bool ChildWindow::OnResizeForDpiAfter() noexcept
{
    // TODO: This won't change font DPI, ex. of controls
    const int dpiX = ToPixelsX(mSizeRect.left);
    const int dpiY = ToPixelsY(mSizeRect.top);
    const int dpiWidth = ToPixelsX(mSizeRect.right);
    const int dpiHeight = ToPixelsY(mSizeRect.bottom);

    return SetWindowPos(mhWnd, HWND_TOP,
        dpiX, dpiY, dpiWidth, dpiHeight,
        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE) != FALSE;
}
```

`mSizeRect` holds DIP size of a window at 96 DPI and is updated when the window size changes

```
/** Window size and position at 96 DPI */
D2D1_RECT_U mSizeRect;

// ToPixelsX is defined as follows
template<typename ReturnType = int, typename Param>
[[nodiscard]] inline ReturnType ToPixelsX(Param dips) const noexcept
{
    // pixels = (DIP × DPI) / 96
    // pixels = DIP x (DPI / 96)
    // mDpiScale = DPI / 96.0
    return static_cast<ReturnType>(std::ceil(dips * mDpiScale.x));
}
```

And `mDipScale` is defined as 96

```
/** Default DPI */
static constexpr float mDefaultDPI = USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;
```

Common controls are intialized as follows:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ctrl{ };
ctrl.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
ctrl.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;

InitCommonControlsEx(&ctrl);
```

Buttons are created with `WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON`

Button text which remains constant is set with ex `SetWindowTextW(hWnd, L"File")`

Hopefully I gave enough information, but fundamental issue is that size of the caption of the common control remain constant after those controls are resized for DPI change.

Question is how to make the font resize as well, and why doesn't font size change?

Common controls are managed by GDI instead of Direct X and according to quote below fonts should resize right?

> GDI and DPI GDI drawing is measured in pixels. That means if your
> program is marked as DPI-aware, and you ask GDI to draw a 200 × 100
> rectangle, the resulting rectangle will be 200 pixels wide and 100
> pixels tall on the screen. However, GDI font sizes are scaled to the
> current DPI setting. In other words, if you create a 72-point font,
> the size of the font will be 96 pixels at 96 DPI, but 144 pixels at
> 144 DPI. Here is a 72 point font rendered at 144 DPI using GDI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DPIAwarenessPerWindow) (referenced from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#per-monitor-dpi-scaling-support-by-ui-framework--technology)) appears to re-create and re-set the font for all child controls on DPI changes, which seems to contradict the quoted documentation.

Comment: On a (possibly unrelated) note: The fonts used in the screenshots look like you aren't using Common Controls [version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-control-versions), or you haven't [enabled Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).

Comment: Are you actually creating and setting a font at all?

Comment: @JonathanPotter No I'm not creating or setting any fonts manually, those are default fonts, should I create them manually?

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for this link, I'll test this method looks promising, btw. I do have visual styles enabled with `#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:` and version specified is 6.0

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you so much again, I've resized font as shown in sample code and it works like charm! It's interesting how MS docs are wrong, You might want to write an answer for this. also setting font manually gives much better font look and feel!

Comment: It's possible that the default system font doesn't get auto-scaled for DPI but user-assigned fonts do. It's also possible the docs are wrong. In any event you should create and set your own font, as literally nothing looks good with the default system font.